Issue: 500 Error - "Failed to load API definition" in .NET 8 Project
Problem Statement:
I am encountering a 500 error with the message "Failed to load API definition" when I build and run my .NET 8 project. The error appears in the UI, indicating a problem with loading the API documentation.
Code Example:
Here is a sample of the code from my ReportsController:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace DMSSWE.SECURITY.WEBAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class ReportsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IReports _bl;
        private readonly string[] connectionValues = new string[2];

        public ReportsController()
        {
            connectionValues[0] = GlobalData.ConnectionString;
            connectionValues[1] = GlobalData.ConnectionType.ToString();

            switch (Convert.ToInt32(connectionValues[1]))
            {
                case (int)ConnectionType.MSSQL:
                    _bl = new ReportsSQL();
                    break;

                case (int)ConnectionType.ORACLE:
                    _bl = new ReportsORA();
                    break;

                case (int)ConnectionType.POSTGRESQL:
                    _bl = new ReportsPGSQL();
                    break;


                default:
                    break;
            }
        }        
      
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("PostReportDetails")]
        public IActionResult PostReportDetails([FromBody] IREPORTSDTO reports)
        {
            try
            {
                bool result = _bl.PostReportDetails(connectionValues, reports);
                return this.Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }
}

Details
Framework: .NET 8
Issue:
UI displays a 500 error with the message "Failed to load API definition" after running the project.
Objective: Understand the cause of the error and find a way to resolve it.
What I've Tried

Checking Connection Strings: Verified that the GlobalData.ConnectionString and GlobalData.ConnectionType are correctly set.
Dependency Injection: Ensured that the dependency injection is properly configured in Program.cs.
Authorization: Verified that the [Authorize] attribute is correctly used and configured.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Can you also show your startup code that sets up the Swagger? It might be a good idea to create a new WebAPI project and compare the code that comes in it with your project.

Seem the code in your ReportsController is not completely ? Could share all the mehtods in this controller.

Thank you to everyone who provided suggestions for resolving the "Failed to load API definition" error in my .NET 8 project. I found the solution to the problem.
The issue was caused by Swagger not supporting the Bitmap type in my DTO. By removing the following line from my code, the error was resolved:
public Bitmap image { get; set; }

After removing this line, the Swagger UI loaded correctly, and the API definition was successfully displayed.
Thanks again for all your help and suggestions!

@Jason Pan, This is my complete code of report controller. When I comment out the first two HttpPost methods, the API loads without any errors.
using DMSSWE.SECURITY.WebAPI.Data.Mssql;
using DMSSWE.SECURITY.WebAPI.Data.Oracale;
using DMSSWE.SECURITY.WEBAPI.Common;
using DMSSWE.SECURITY.WebAPI.Data.Interfaces;
using DMSSWE.SECURITY.Models;
using DMSSWE.SECURITY.Reports.Datesets;
using static DMSSWE.SECURITY.Common.Enums;
using DMSSWE.SECURITY.WebAPI.Data.Postgresql;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace DMSSWE.SECURITY.WEBAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class ReportsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IReports _bl;
        private readonly string[] connectionValues = new string[2];

        public ReportsController()
        {
            connectionValues[0] = GlobalData.ConnectionString;
            connectionValues[1] = GlobalData.ConnectionType.ToString();

            switch (Convert.ToInt32(connectionValues[1]))
            {
                case (int)ConnectionType.MSSQL:
                    _bl = new ReportsSQL();
                    break;

                case (int)ConnectionType.ORACLE:
                    _bl = new ReportsORA();
                    break;

                case (int)ConnectionType.POSTGRESQL:
                    _bl = new ReportsPGSQL();
                    break;


                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("PostReportDetails")]
        public IActionResult PostReportDetails([FromBody] IREPORTSDTO reports)
        {
            try
            {
                bool result = _bl.PostReportDetails(connectionValues, reports);
                return this.Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("PutReportDetails")]
        public IActionResult PutReportDetails([FromBody] IREPORTSDTO reports)
        {
            try
            {
                bool result = _bl.PutReportDetails(connectionValues, reports);
                return this.Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("DeleteReportDetails")]
        public IActionResult DeleteReportDetails(int moduleId, int functionId, string reportId)
        {
            try
            {
                bool result = _bl.DeleteReportDetails(connectionValues, moduleId, functionId, reportId);
                return this.Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetAllReports")]
        public IActionResult GetAllReports(string companyId, string productId, int moduleId, string userId)
        {
            try
            {
                List<IREPORTSDTO> reports = _bl.GetAllReports(connectionValues, companyId, productId, moduleId, userId);
                return this.Ok(reports);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetReportDetails")]
        public IActionResult GetReportDetails(int moduleId, int functionId, string reportId)
        {
            try
            {
                IREPORTSDTO report = _bl.GetReportDetails(connectionValues, moduleId, functionId, reportId);
                return this.Ok(report);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetSecurityConnection")]
        public SECURITYCONNDTO GetSecurityConnection()
        {
            return GlobalData.SecurityConnection;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetReportSE0001")]
        public IActionResult GetReportSE0001(string userId)
        {
            try
            {
                RPT_USER_MATRIX ds = _bl.GetReportSE0001(connectionValues, userId);
                return this.Ok(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetReportSE0002")]
        public IActionResult GetReportSE0002(int accountStatus)
        {
            try
            {
                RPT_USER_ACNT_STATUS ds = _bl.GetReportSE0002(connectionValues, accountStatus);
                return this.Ok(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetReportSE0003")]
        public IActionResult GetReportSE0003(int usrPwdStatus)
        {
            try
            {
                RPT_USER_PWD_STATUS ds = _bl.GetReportSE0003(connectionValues, usrPwdStatus);
                return this.Ok(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetReportSE0004")]
        public IActionResult GetReportSE0004(string userId)
        {
            try
            {
                RPT_USER_MATRIX ds = _bl.GetReportSE0004(connectionValues, userId);
                return this.Ok(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetReportSE0006")]
        public IActionResult GetReportSE0006(string userId)
        {
            try
            {
                RPT_USER_MATRIX ds = _bl.GetReportSE0006(connectionValues, userId);
                return this.Ok(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetReportSE0007")]
        public IActionResult GetReportSE0007(string productId)
        {
            try
            {
                RPT_ROLE_MATRIX ds = _bl.GetReportSE0007(connectionValues, productId);
                return this.Ok(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetReportSE0008")]
        public IActionResult GetReportSE0008(string productId)
        {
            try
            {
                RPT_ROLE_MATRIX ds = _bl.GetReportSE0008(connectionValues, productId);
                return this.Ok(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetReportSE0010")]
        public IActionResult GetReportSE0010(string fromDate, string toDate, string loginUser)
        {
            try
            {
                RPT_USER_ID_AUDIT ds = _bl.GetReportSE0010(connectionValues, fromDate, toDate, loginUser);
                return this.Ok(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetReportSE0011")]
        public IActionResult GetReportSE0011(string fromDate, string toDate, string loginUser)
        {
            try
            {
                RPT_UPM_AUDIT ds = _bl.GetReportSE0011(connectionValues, fromDate, toDate, loginUser);
                return this.Ok(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetReportSE0012")]
        public IActionResult GetReportSE0012(string fromDate, string toDate, string loginUser)
        {
            try
            {
                RPT_USER_LOGIN_AUDIT ds = _bl.GetReportSE0012(connectionValues, fromDate, toDate, loginUser);
                return this.Ok(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetReportSE0013")]
        public IActionResult GetReportSE0013(string fromDate, string toDate, string loginUser)
        {
            try
            {
                RPT_USER_ACCESS_AUDIT ds = _bl.GetReportSE0013(connectionValues, fromDate, toDate, loginUser);
                return this.Ok(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetReportSE0014")]
        public IActionResult GetReportSE0014(string fromDate, string toDate, string loginUser)
        {
            try
            {
                RPT_USER_ACTIVITY_AUDIT ds = _bl.GetReportSE0014(connectionValues, fromDate, toDate, loginUser);
                return this.Ok(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetReportSE0015")]
        public IActionResult GetReportSE0015(string loginUser)
        {
            try
            {
                RPT_USER_LIST ds = _bl.GetReportSE0015(connectionValues, loginUser);
                return this.Ok(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }
}


I have checked it and can't reproduce it, it hard to say what happened? The code is correct, could you share your .csproj file to us? We also need to check the package version.

@Meligy,Here is my Startup.cs file
using DMSSWE.SECURITY.WebAPI.Bussiness.HealthCheck;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using System;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using DMSSWE.SECURITY.WEBAPI.Common;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        policyBuilder =>
        {
            policyBuilder.WithOrigins(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AllowedOrigins")?.Split(",") ?? new string[0]);
            policyBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
            policyBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();
            policyBuilder.AllowCredentials();
        });
});


// Set the global variables
JwtConfig.SecretKey = builder.Configuration["JWT:Secret"];
JwtConfig.Issuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:Issue"];
JwtConfig.Audience = builder.Configuration["JWT:Audience"];
JwtConfig.TokenValidityInMinutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(builder.Configuration["JWT:TokenValidityInMinutes"]));
JwtConfig.RefreshTokenValidityInMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(builder.Configuration["JWT:RefreshTokenValidityInMinutes"]);

// Add services to the container.
var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidIssuer = JwtConfig.Issuer,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidAudience = JwtConfig.Audience,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = JwtConfig.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
};

builder.Services.AddSingleton(tokenValidationParameters);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new() { Title = "Security API", Version = "v1" });

    // Define the OAuth2.0 scheme that's in use (i.e., Implicit Flow)
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        Scheme = "bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT"
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[] {}
        }
    });
});

#region Set Global Parameters

DMSSWE.SECURITY.WEBAPI.Common.SecurityConnectionManager.GetSecurityDetails(builder.Configuration["AppSettings:SecurityCfgFilepath"] ?? string.Empty);

#endregion Set Global Parameters

builder.Services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck<SqlServerHealthCheck>("Sql Server");


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions
{
    ResponseWriter = async (context, report) =>
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        var result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(
            new
            {
                status = report.Status.ToString(),
                checks = report.Entries.Select(entry => new
                {
                    name = entry.Key,
                    status = entry.Value.Status.ToString(),
                    description = entry.Value.Description
                }),
                duration = report.TotalDuration
            });
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
});
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


Hi Jinushi, I have checked your Program.cs file, it seems  correct, no error. Could you share the full code in your ReportsController , if there is any sensitive informations, you can hide it, I just want to check all the methods and the attributes.

Hi, I've already provided the complete code for the report controller above. @Jason Pan
